# Putting a matrix from a text file into a list

Tags: python, performance, parsing, file, matrix

I'm trying to read a text file with matrix and put it in a list, but I am using two loops here and I want my function to be faster.

```
def read_file(path_to_file):
    mylist=[]
    for eachLine in open(path_to_file,'rt'):
        mylist.append([int(eachRow) for eachRow in eachLine.split()])
    return mylist
```

Comment: Since the result will be a list of lists and `int` can handle only one number at a time, you have to have 2 loops of some sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible to make this faster. But it can be better:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'rt') as fh:
    return [[int(value) for value in line.split()] for line in fh]
```

First of all, you should always use a `with ...` context manager when working with files. That way you cannot forget to close the file handle after you are done reading from it.

Other improvements:

- More natural variable names
- Simpler and more compact writing style using a list comprehension

Also keep in mind [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.